# How to query multiple SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me

I have:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE(idfish INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl1 (idfish)
VALUES (10), (11), (12)

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(kindid INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl2 (kindid)
VALUES (1), (2)

SELECT * FROM @tbl1
SELECT * FROM @tbl2
```

Now, I want result have two columns 
Table(idfish, kindid) as:

```
10 1 ;11 1; 12 1; 10 2; 11 2; 12 2
```

After ';' as new row

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just join on a common value.

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl1
INNER JOIN @tbl2 ON 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a cross join:

```
select * from @tbl1 cross join @tbl2;
```

Comment: tks you very much ^^